# Зависла джоба gitlab ci

Tags: docker, docker-compose, развертывание, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке развернуть проект на сервере возникла проблема: джобой с использованием Docker зависла и не удается выполнить сборку проекта. Я попробовал разные методы решения, включая перезапуск сервера и рестарт ранера так же проверил локально докер он успешно поднялся. Однако, в джобе Docker все еще не завершается и уже прошло 30 минут без видимого прогресса. В чем может быть проблемы?